# How can I make a simple number guessing game more efficient?

Tags: c++, optimization, game

I have been programming a simple number guessing game and I am wondering if there is any way of making my code more efficient and cleaner. I have spent some time on it implementing error checking to make it as safe as I know how. I feel as if the way's that I have done this may be 'long winded' so if you know of a shorter way to do so then this would be much appreciated.

I do have comments, and I hope they make the program readable!

I am using Visual Studio 2010 - not sure if this changes much.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// Include the standard namespace for easy use of cout/cin
using namespace std;

// Function Declarations.
string convertIntToString(int input);
bool isValidInput_Int(string input);
void cls();
void pause();
void printError(int ErrorNumber, bool ClearWindow);
void game(int difficulty);

// Main Function
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Variables
    string input;
    int inputVal;
    bool gameIsRunning = true;

    // We want rand() to be as random as possible.
    srand( time(NULL) );

    // Run until the user wishes to quit.
    while(gameIsRunning)
    {
        cout << "Welcome to the number guessing game V1.0\n\nPlease select an option:\n";
        cout << "1- Easy\n2- Medium\n3- Hard\n4- Expert\n5- Exit\n>>";

        cin >> input;

        // Check if the data is valid according to our wishes.
        if(isValidInput_Int(input))
        {
            // Act correctly according to the input.

            // Store the integer we want.
            inputVal = atoi(input.c_str());

            // Make sure the input is a correct selection
            if(inputVal < 5 && inputVal > 0)
            {
                // Run the game.
                game(inputVal);
            }
            else if(inputVal == 5)
            {
                // Quit the application.
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                printError(2, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printError(1, true);
        }

    }

    // Leave the Application.
    return 0;
}

///--------------------------------------
/// Resource:
/// http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/7777/
/// Converts an integer to a string.
///--------------------------------------
string convertIntToString(int input)
{
   stringstream ss; //create a stringstream
   ss << input;     //add number to the stream
   return ss.str(); //return a string with the contents of the stream
}

///--------------------------------------
/// Checks if the input is of size 1 and
/// The values inside this are of type
/// Integer and nothing else.
///--------------------------------------
bool isValidInput_Int(string input)
{
    bool retVal = 0;
    try
    {
        if(atoi(input.c_str()))
            retVal = 1;
    }
    catch(exception)
    {
        retVal = 0;
    }
    return retVal;
}

///--------------------------------------
/// Clears the console window of text.
///--------------------------------------
void cls()
{
    system("cls");
    return;
}

///--------------------------------------
/// Pauses the console window.
///--------------------------------------
void pause()
{
    system("pause");
    return;
}

///--------------------------------------
/// Shows an error based on the input to
/// The function. If your error is not
/// Listed then put '0' in as a default
/// value. This returns a some-what
/// Generic message to the use.
///--------------------------------------
void printError(int ErrorNumber, bool ClearWindow)
{
    // Clear the console window
    if(ClearWindow)
        cls();

    switch(ErrorNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "---Error: Invalid Input---\n\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "---Error: Please enter a correct option---\n\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "---Error: Something went wrong---\n\n";
            break;
    }
    return;
}

///--------------------------------------
/// This is where the 'game' code is kept
///--------------------------------------
void game(int difficulty)
{
    // Variables
    string input;
    string message;
    int inputVal;
    // Generate our random number!
    int numberToGuess = rand() % ((difficulty * 2) * 10) + 1;

    cout << "Welcome!\n";
    cout << "You have 10 lives.\nThe number is between 1 and " << (difficulty * 2) * 10 << "\n";
    cout << "Start guessing!\n\n";

    // Loop until they are dead or they guess the number.
    for(int lives = 10;lives > 0; lives--)
    {
        cout << ">>";
        cin >> input;

        // Check if the data is valid according to our wishes.
        if(isValidInput_Int(input))
        {
            // Store the integer we want.
            inputVal = atoi(input.c_str());

            // Check if the guess was correct or not
            // If it isnt, give them some 'guidance'.
            if(inputVal == numberToGuess)
            {
                message = "Congratulations!\nYou Win!\n";
                lives -= 10;
            }

            if(lives != 1)
            {
                if(inputVal > numberToGuess)
                {
                    message = "Incorrect, try guessing lower!\n";
                }

                if(inputVal < numberToGuess)
                {
                    message = "Incorrect, try guessing higher!\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Incorrect, the number was: [" + convertIntToString(numberToGuess) + "]\n";
            }

            cout << message;
        }
        else
        {
            // Let them know that there input was invalid.
            printError(1, false);
            // We could 'punish' however, we will be nice.
            lives++;
        }
    }

    // Pause.
    pause();

    // Clear the screen before showing the menu again.
    cls();
    return;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you modify the question title to include more information about your specific issue (because "help me make my code better" is *everyone's* goal here :) ).

Comment: I am new to c++ and I want to make sure that when I code I am doing everything correctly. I know that 'in general' everyone is trying ot improve there code, however, since I am somewhat new, I dont know as much as you do. I'll think of a more specific title though if I can. :)

Comment: Flyphe, I just meant something like "How can I make a simple number guessing game more efficient" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here some of my language-focused remarks, not touching the actual program design.

### usings

```
// Include the standard namespace for easy use of cout/cin
using namespace std;
```

Very nice to list what you need by adding the comment. But instead of pulling all names you could make it more explicit

```
using std::cin;
using std::cout
```

In big files you may want to "sectionize" the using by from which `#include` they came from. (Edit, thanks to comment below) Best do not introduce `using` before other `#includes` though, you can group the using afterwards. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
// for shorten code
using std::string;
using std::map;
using std::vector;
// from iostreeam
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
```

I do **not** do this for **all names**, only for the most frequent ones when it really saves space -- and most people do know anyway. Most `std::`-items I write *with* their namespace when I use them.

`string` I often apply a `using` to (lots of strings in function arguments), but `map` and `vector` I typically do not (better being explicit at the few location they are used). When I have to use lots of `std::vector<thingy>::const_iterator` somewhere I shorten the code with a local `typedef` or `using`.

```
void drawData(std::vector<thingy> &data) {
    typedef std::vector<thingy>::const_iterator tit;
    const tit end = data.end();
    for(tit it=data.begin(); it!=end; ++it) {
        *it.drawYourself();
    }
}
```

And with C++11 you do not even need that, you have `auto` and ranged-`for` to beautify your.

### variable initialization

```
// Variables
string input;
int inputVal;
bool gameIsRunning = true;
```

It is ok **not to initialize** `string`, because it is a class/object.

But you **should initialize** `int` variables.

### latest possible declaration

```
// Variables
string input;

...
while(...)
   ...
   cin >> input;
```

Your rule-of-thumb should be to declare a variable **as late as possible** which would mean

```
...
while(...)
   ...
   string input;
   cin >> input;
```

The exception are "tight loops" when the frequent initialization and destruction would cost to much. But actually, `string` is quite cheap and this is not a "tight loop", so I would recommend it.

Answer (score 6):

## On Comments

> I do have comments, I hope they make the program readable!

Unfortunately, no. Your comments don’t help readability and only take up unnecessary space (which makes the program *less* readable).

The problem is that your comments convey useless information. For instance,

```
// Pause.
pause();
```

How is this comment helping?

There’s a commonly-quoted adage,

> Code explains the *how*, comments explain the *why*

which actually covers most cases: use *code* to explain *how* a solution is implemented. Only use comments when necessary to explain *why* you do something.

In practice, this means that most code doesn’t need comments at all, good code should ideally be self-explanatory; if it isn’t, take that as a hint to rewrite it.

Here’s a positive example, however:

```
// We could 'punish' however, we will be nice.
lives++;
```

Now *this* comment is more helpful. But it could still be a bit clearer.

There’s one exception to this no-comments rule:

*Do* provide documentation for all functions via comments. But again, use the documentation to explain stuff that is not explained by the function name and signature.

For instance,

```
///--------------------------------------
/// Pauses the console window.
///--------------------------------------
void pause();
```

… not particularly helpful. What does “pauses the console window” actually mean? A more helpful description would be, “Halts execution until the user hits any hey”.

Your other function documentations are much better in this regard. But take care to explicitly describe all *parameters*, the *return value*, and all *side effects*.

## Implementation

(In addition to what @towi already wrote.)

### Input

Your input routine does three times the work:

1. It inputs a string
2. It tests whether this is a valid number, via `isValidInput_Int`.
3. It converts it to a number via `atoi`.

`isValidInput_int` is actually a lot of boilerplate code doing the same thing as just calling `atoi`. In fact, `isValidInput_int` doesn’t work at all because `atoi` *cannot* be used reliably to test whether a valid number was entered. It doesn’t throw an exception, it just silently returns `0`. You have no way of knowing whether the user entered `0` or an invalid number.

Furthermore, `isValidInput_int` uses the `bool` type but you never actually use the `bool` constants `true` and `false`, instead you use `1` and `0`. Do *not* do this. Unfortunately, C++ allows this but it’s a weakness of the type system (thanks to C).

Furthermore, `atoi` is redundant here anyway, just input the number directly. That is, instead of reading a string, do this:

```
int difficulty;
if (cin >> difficulty) {
    // Input was succesful, proceed.
}
else {
    printError(1, true);
}
```

### Use meaningful variable names

`(difficulty * 2) * 10` crops up several times. What does it mean? Put it into a meaningful variable to increase readability (`range` would be a meaningful name).

`inputVal` describes where the value comes from, but not what it signifies. How about `nextGuess` instead?

Also, you should settle on a single convention for names. At the moment you mix between camelCase and under_score, sometimes_WithCapital_Letters. Modern C++ code generally uses lowercase_words_separated_by_underscore but you’re free to use your own convention – the important thing is *consistency*.

### Other stuff

You seem to always finish your functions with `return;` – that’s redundant. You only need `return` if you want to return a value, or if you want to exit the function *prematurely*. At the end of a function, you don’t need it.

Furthermore, `main` is a special case, `return 0;` is implied at the end of it, so this is also redundant (but all other functions that return values need explicit `return`s).

Finally, the logic flow in `game` isn’t entirely obvious. This could be cleared up. In particular, when do lives go up and down? It might help to simplify the input reading routine (see above) and to extract the guess into a separate function. In general, try to limit the level of nesting drastically. Four levels of nesting (here, a `for` and three `ifs`) should really be the exception. Your logic here could really be simplified, for instance by reversing the condition `if (lives != 1)`, and exiting the loop early:

```
if(lives == 1)
{
    cout << "Incorrect, the number was: [" + convertIntToString(numberToGuess) + "]\n";
    break;
}

if(inputVal > numberToGuess)
{
    message = "Incorrect, try guessing lower!\n";
}

if(inputVal < numberToGuess)
{
    message = "Incorrect, try guessing higher!\n";
}
```

In my opinion, this still isn’t as readable as it could be because it takes up a lot of unnecessary *vertical space*. I find the following *much* more readable but be aware that this opinion isn’t shared by all.

```
if(lives == 1) {
    cout << "Incorrect, the number was: [" + convertIntToString(numberToGuess) + "]\n";
    break;
}

if(inputVal > numberToGuess)
    message = "Incorrect, try guessing lower!\n";

if(inputVal < numberToGuess)
    message = "Incorrect, try guessing higher!\n";
```

Some people will hate me for giving this advice but they probably wear their pants on their head. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I agree with everything you wrote, appart from the last section :P. I like to have the brackets there and on the same line as then it makes it easier to add additional code later on plus, in my opinion it is easier so see where a function/loop starts and ends. I agree however with the layout that you used as it is better, so thanks. I shall try to make my comments more usefull and helpful. Again, I would upvote you if I could!

Comment: Also, the reason for adding the 'return;' at the end of void functions is because I was told that it is good practice. Thanks for telling me otherwise, I didn't think it was of any use anyway :)